# SwiftUI View not updating based on @ObservedObject

Tags: ios, arrays, swiftui, observableobject

In the following code, an observed object is updated but the View that observes it is not. Any idea why?

The code presents on the screen 10 numbers (0..<10) and a button. Whenever the button is pressed, it randomly picks one of the 10 numbers and flips its visibility (visible→hidden or vice versa).

The print statement shows that the button is updating the numbers, but the View does not update accordingly. I know that updating a value in an array does not change the array value itself, so I use a manual `objectWillChange.send()` call. I would have thought that should trigger the update, but the screen never changes.

Any idea? I'd be interested in a solution using `NumberLine` as a class, or as a struct, or using no `NumberLine` type at all and instead rather just using an array variable within the `ContentView` struct.

[image: Screenshot]

**Here's the code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var numberLine = NumberLine()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< numberLine.visible.count) { number in
                    if self.numberLine.visible[number] {
                        Text(String(number)).font(.title).padding(5)
                    }
                }
            }.padding()

            Button(action: {
                let index = Int.random(in: 0 ..< self.numberLine.visible.count)
                self.numberLine.objectWillChange.send()
                self.numberLine.visible[index].toggle()
                print("\(index) now \(self.numberLine.visible[index] ? "shown" : "hidden")")
            }) {
                Text("Change")
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}

class NumberLine: ObservableObject {
    var visible: [Bool] = Array(repeatElement(true, count: 10))
}
```

Comment: in my case it was a stupid issue, i had to put the observedObject being updated on main thread... suddentlly everythiing start working as expected

Answer (score 40):

With `@ObservedObject` everything's fine... let's analyse...

**Iteration 1:**

Take your code without changes and add just the following line (shows as text current state of `visible` array)

```
VStack { // << right below this
    Text("\(numberLine.visible.reduce(into: "") { $0 += $1 ? "Y" : "N"} )")
```

and run, and you see that `Text` is updated so observable object works

[image: demo]

**Iteration 2:**

Remove `self.numberLine.objectWillChange.send()` and use instead default `@Published` pattern in view model

```
class NumberLinex: ObservableObject {
    @Published var visible: [Bool] = Array(repeatElement(true, count: 10))
}
```

run and you see that update works the same as on 1st demo above.

*But... main numbers in `ForEach` still not updated... yes, because problem in `ForEach` - you used constructor with `Range` that generates **constant** view's group **by-design** (that documented!).

!! That is the reason - you need dynamic `ForEach`, but for that model needs to be changed.

**Iteration 3 - Final:**

Dynamic `ForEach` constructor requires that iterating data elements be identifiable, so we need struct as model and updated view model.

Here is final solution & demo (tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4)

[image: demo2]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var numberLine = NumberLine()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(numberLine.visible, id: \.id) { number in
                    Group {
                        if number.visible {
                            Text(String(number.id)).font(.title).padding(5)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.padding()

            Button("Change") {
                let index = Int.random(in: 0 ..< self.numberLine.visible.count)
                self.numberLine.visible[index].visible.toggle()
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}

class NumberLine: ObservableObject {
    @Published var visible: [NumberItem] = (0..<10).map { NumberItem(id: $0) }
}

struct NumberItem {
    let id: Int
    var visible = true
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @asperi! The question remains for me of why the `if number.visible` clause surrounding the `Text()` views didn't prevent the invisible numbers from showing. Is it that when the `ForEach` iterates over a constant collection it doesn't even receive the notification that the `numberLine` in its closure has changed?

Comment: I was having the same problem on iOS 13 with xcode 11.6, but not on iOS 14 beta. I was using indeed the range approach. then I changed to have an identifiable model, but the problem persisted. Adding @published to the property made the trick for me. iOS 14 beta worked all the time.

Comment: What is the expected error? When I run the original code by the poster in Xcode 12.1, clicking the button does change the output. So either I'm misunderstanding the error or Swift changed how it handles this case?

Comment: Thank you!! I owe a huge debt of thanks to: 1) Anton for taking the time to post this code, 2) @Asperi for knowing the answer and taking the time to write it out, 3) StackOverflow for having created a platform where the two of you could find each other, and 4) Google for miraculously transforming my rather vague query into the _exact_ StackOverflow link that that I needed. It took me all of 2 minutes to debug a thing I was fearing would take hours. Who knew about this behavior of `ForEach` !? 

Answer (score 26):

I faced the same issue.
For me, replacing **@ObservedObject** with **@StateObject** worked.

Comment: This change solving the problem has no connection with the problem here.

Comment: I found this question facing a similar issue regarding async changes not updating an ObservedObject, and indeed this change solved my problem as well. No idea why, but if anyone comes across this thread be sure to give this a try.

Comment: An instance of `ObservableObject` wrapped in `@StateObject` is tied to the view's lifecycle, while one in `@ObservedObject` is not. I don't know why it solves anything in this example, though.

Answer (score 5):

Using your insight, @Asperi, that the problem is with the `ForEach` and not with the `@ObservableObject` functionality, here's a small modification to the original that does the trick:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var numberLine = NumberLine()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(Array(0..<10).filter {numberLine.visible[$0]}, id: \.self) { number in
                    Text(String(number)).font(.title).padding(5)
                }
            }.padding()

            Button(action: {
                let index = Int.random(in: 0 ..< self.numberLine.visible.count)
                self.numberLine.visible[index].toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Change")
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}

class NumberLine: ObservableObject {
    @Published var visible: [Bool] = Array(repeatElement(true, count: 10))
}
```

Comment: Exactly, the issue is not with the '@ObservableObject', need to wrap datasource in '@ObservableObject'

Answer (score 2):

This answer might not be useful until **XCode15/iOS17** is released but I'm using the beta right now.

I'm showing a list of MyItem in a Table and I just want the row to update when the status changes but no matter what I can't get this to happen without some .id() hack on the grid.

I tried conforming to hashable and identifiable and setting .self as the id for the rows, along with a bunch of other things, without getting this to work.

Then I simply tried using the new `Observable` macro and it works flawlessly.

Original Code:

```
class MyParentObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [MyItem]()
}

class MyItem: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var status: MyStatusEnum = .ready
}
```

Working Code:

```
class MyParentObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [MyItem]()
}

@Observable class MyItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var status: MyStatusEnum = .ready
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is **nothing Wrong** with ***observed object***, you should use `@Published` in use of ***observed object***, but my code works without it as well. And also I updated your logic in your code.

---

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model = NumberLineModel()
    @State private var lastIndex: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 30.0) {
            
            HStack {
                
                ForEach(0..<model.array.count) { number in
                    
                    if model.array[number] {
                        Text(String(number)).padding(5)
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            .font(.title).statusBar(hidden: true)
            
            Group {
                
                if let unwrappedValue: Int = lastIndex { Text("Now the number " + unwrappedValue.description + " is hidden!") }
                else { Text("All numbers are visible!") }
                
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .font(Font.headline)
            
            
            
            Button(action: {
                
                if let unwrappedIndex: Int = lastIndex { model.array[unwrappedIndex] = true }
                
                let newIndex: Int = Int.random(in: 0...9)
                model.array[newIndex] = false
                lastIndex = newIndex
                
                
            }) { Text("shuffle") }
            
        }
        
    }
}

class NumberLineModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var array: [Bool] = Array(repeatElement(true, count: 10))
    
}
```

---

Comment: Thank you, swiftPunk, but your code is solving a different problem from mine. Yours works because it replaces every eliminated number with another, resulting in a constant number of items in the ForEach. As @Asperi pointed out above, mine failed because it required a variable number of items on the screen… but the ForEach variety I was using was the one requiring a constant number of items. He explains it well in his solution, and mine merely streamlines his.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the function, do not forget to add `id: \.self` in your ForEach function, and make your Model `Hashable, Identifiable`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and after hours of trial and error it finally worked. My problem was that I setup my views with `ForEach` in SwiftUI and only referenced the `id: \.id`. By doing so, views did not update when a `@Published var` within my `@ObservedObject` got updated.

The solution is as Amir mentioned: An `@ObservedObject` needs to conform to `Hashable, Identifiable` and the `ForEach` must not use the `id` to be identified, but instead either explicitly use `id: \.self` or it also can be omitted in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was creating multiple instance of ObservableObject class. I had to make it singleton so that the state is shared between views.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I came here because I have a Model of a card game, and it is encapsulated inside a View Model. But updates were not happening in the View as the model changed, as expected.

My Model is a class (could be a struct) called X, and the ViewModel is a class called XGame which encapsulates the Model as a private var.

```
// The View Model
class XGame : ObservableObject {
  private var model = X() // OOPS! This was my mistake here
}

// The View
struct ContentView : View {
  @ObservedObject var game: XGame = XGame()
//etc.
}
```

So once I fixed the View Model and put @Published in front of the private var model (as per below) then everything started working as expected.

```
// The View Model
class XGame : ObservableObject {
  @Published private var model = X() // Now it works!
}
```